# Dynamic Paging Bar Position in Telerik RadGrid Component

Tags: .net, events, gridview, telerik, radgrid

I've got a component, inheriting from Telerik RadGrid (.NET) and I want to set the `PagerStyle.Position` to `GridPagerPosition.TopAndBottom` if I've got more than 50 rows on that page or to `GridPagerPosition.Bottom` otherwise.

I've tried several events that are called once per page load (not once per item) like `OnNeedDataSource`, `ControlPreRender`, `OnDataPropertyChanged` but I cannot reliably get the `Count` of the rows. It comes back as -1 or zero even though the `DataSource` object is populated. I might be too early in those events? Checking the component's life cycle didn't help either.

Where to put the `if (count > 50) ...`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822075/cannot-identify-selected-page-in-telerik-grid-i-need-selected-page-to-be-underl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom pager because I needed some special features. In there it was straight forward to call the GridPagingManager (`_pagingMgr`):

```
_tblView.PagerStyle.Position = _pagingMgr.LastIndexInPage - _pagingMgr.FirstIndexInPage > 50 
            ? GridPagerPosition.TopAndBottom 
            : GridPagerPosition.Bottom;`
```

Done!